# Arduino compatible sensor for motion detection and positioning

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project that requires motion detection and positioning. I've worked substantially with a camera but the issue with this is that I need something sleek, small and not heavy at all. Cameras also tend to rely on luminosity and they don't work well in poorly lit spaces.

I need someone who's worked on something like this or who knows the best sensor for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* elias akin, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 2):

"I am working on a project that requires motion detection and positioning"

Could a be bit more precise? In the title you just asked for motion detection, now you also want positioning.

What do you want to detect - a door or a fly? At which distance? With which accuracy? At which frame rate?

This would be something to at least detect motion and measure the distance to it: [Infrared Sensor 4-30 cm - Sharp GP2Y0A41SK0F](https://www.antratek.de/sharp-gp2y0a41sk0f?gclid=CIfMltmd1cYCFcnItAodkQ8ESQ).